# How can I make sure users are turning in correct input, for Guess game in python 3.5.1?

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x, input

This is my code:

```
from random import randint
print("What is your name?")
name=input()
tries=0
number= randint(1,100)
print("Hello, %s guess a number from 0 to 100" % name)
while tries < 8:
    print("Take a Guess")
    guess=input()
    guess=int(guess)
    if guess < number:
        print("Too Low")
        tries += 1
    if guess > number:
        print("Too High")
        tries += 1
    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
   print("You got it, in %s tries" % tries)

if guess != number:
    print("Sorry try again!")
```

But it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Zuazua/PycharmProjects/untitled/GuessMyNumber2.py", line 10, in <module>
    guess=int(guess)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '23!'
```

Comment: Error is self explaining.

Comment: @DmitryPoroh Perhaps not to a newbie!

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `guess=int(guess)` into this:

```
guess=int(re.search(r'\d+', guess).group())
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to parse entered value with `guess=int(guess)` can lead to different exceptions. Quick and dirty way to fix it - is to wrap it in `try ... except` block. Like:

```
try:
    guess=int(guess)
except ValueError:
    print("Cannot understand your input. Pls, try again")
    continue
```

This code will catch all ValueError exceptions occured during parsing. You may find here more info on exceptions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#errors-and-exceptions